# SAP Cloud Platform WEB IDE Fullstack .che folder

Tags: sapui5

Should we remove the .che folder from Git when we use Web IDE Full-Stack?

Comment: Depends on what's inside

Comment: project.json which changes everytime when we deploy

Comment: Then I'd remove it from Git

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is to never include IDE-specific files into a Git repository. There are several articles and blogs on this and I would point you to this one: [IDE Project Files In Version Control - Yes or No? Of Course, Not!](https://dzone.com/articles/ide-project-files-version)

The main drawbacks of having IDE specific files checked-in are the following:

- Each IDE would add its own files. E.g. if some of your developers would decide to use VSCode, then you would also have a `.vscode` folder in there.
- The file structure may be different depending on the IDE version (if you use the SAP Web IDE Cloud, this should not be an issue, but it might be if one developer is using the local WebIDE).
- The files change very frequently and lead to merge conflicts. E.g. if you do a deploy and also one of your colleagues does a deploy, then you will have a conflict when you want to merge your branch with his (assuming that you work on parallel branches).
- The files may contain environment-specific settings. E.g. the name of the project folder, which may actually be different for each developer.

The only clear advantage is that setting up the project after a clone operation might be faster *marginally* (i.e. the developer which is doing the clone might have to do some settings locally on his copy).